# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS can not upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade

After running sudo apt update on my terminal I am informed that 32 packages can be updated.

However, upon trying to upgrade I receive the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  fonts-opensymbol libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common
  libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-zh-cn libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-zh-cn libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-writer libuno-cppu3
  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 python3-uno uno-libs-private ure
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

Any ideas?

Jay

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt full-upgrade` as there are cases where `apt upgrade` cannot apply all upgrades as package removals are required; the other `apt` options allow that to be done  (*your issue maybe related to phased-updates too*)

Comment: I tried a full -upgrade the first time but  forgot the dash so it did not work.  

Worked perfectly this time.  Thanks!